# mysqli_fetch_assoc returns ONLY the first element of the array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a project, where the logged in user should be able to post notes on the homepage, and being logged in the certain user's notes should be printed above the new note form. 
I've written a function for that, where the `mysqli_query` recognizes all the 6 entries I have, but the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` prints only the first note out of 6. What could I do wrong? Here is my code:

```html
<?php    
    function find_notes_by_id($user_id) {
 global $connection;
 
 $safe_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user_id);
 
 $query = 'SELECT content ';
 $query .= 'FROM notes ';
 $query .= 'WHERE user_id = '.$safe_user_id;
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 
 //mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6 [type] => 0 )

 confirm_query($result);

 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 //Array ( [content] => First! ) = it only shows the very first element
 return $row;
}
?>

<?php
$notes_set = find_notes_by_id($userRow['id']);
  foreach($notes_set as $note){
 echo $note;
 echo "<br />";
  }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: you have to create array and then return it to get all record

Comment: Do you mean like `$row = array();`, then the query? Just tried but it works the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.You need to iterate over your `result-set object` through `while()`***

***2.Save all your data to an `array` and then return that `array` to get all records***

*like below:-*

```
<?php    
  function find_notes_by_id($user_id) {
   global $connection;

    $safe_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user_id);

    $query = "SELECT `content` FROM `notes` WHERE `user_id` = $safe_user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    confirm_query($result);

    $final_data = array(); // create an array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // iterate over the result-set object to get all data
        $final_data[] = $row; //assign value to the array
    }
    return $final_data; // return array
  }
?>
```

***Now:-***

```
<?php
$notes_set = find_notes_by_id($userRow['id']);

print_r($notes_set) ; // print result to check array structure so that you can use it correctly in foreach
  foreach($notes_set as $note){
    echo $note['content'];
    echo "<br />";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Now it retrieves all the notes, but it signs "array to string conversion" at the second part's `echo $note;`, why?

Comment: `echo $note['content'];` was the solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @sklrboy  welcome. cheers :):). Glad to help you. Mean while you can up-vote others also if they are useful too.

Comment: @NanaPartykar we have to because when we promote right one, Peoples got help.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all results like so:

```
$arr = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Or use a while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['content'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Answer (score 1):

Save data into an `array`. Use it through `foreach` or `for` loop.

```
$content = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $content[] = $row['content'];
}
return $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change the function like this

```
function find_notes_by_id($user_id) {
    global $connection;

    $safe_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user_id);

    $query = 'SELECT content ';
    $query .= 'FROM notes ';
    $query .= 'WHERE user_id = '.$safe_user_id;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    //mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6 [type] => 0 )

    confirm_query($result);
    $row = array();
    while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //Array ( [content] => First! ) = it only shows the very first element
        $row[] = $result1;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: @Anant Sorry i just used the same variable twice

Comment: Now it's correct. i edited that part. +10 to you too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over.
Problem is with this code

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
return $row;
```

Change that to

```
$x = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $x[] = $row;
}
return $x;
```

Comment: it will return the last value only not all result. think for a second about your logic.

Comment: yeh I missed array symbol

Answer (score 1):

Instead declaring $connection as global pass the $connection variable to the function which would be a efficient way and get the result as array

```
<?php    
            function find_notes_by_id($user_id,$connection) {

            $safe_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user_id);

            $query = 'SELECT content ';
            $query .= 'FROM notes ';
            $query .= 'WHERE user_id = '.$safe_user_id;
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


            confirm_query($result);

         $data = array(); // create an array
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
         $data[] = $row; 
    }
      return $data;
        }
        ?>
```

Now call the function like this

```
 <?php
$notes_set = find_notes_by_id($userRow['id'],$connection);
  foreach($notes_set as $note){
    echo $note['content'];  
  }
?>
```